# Java Racing Game background not moving properly

Tags: java, jlabel, sprite, imageicon

So I'm making a racing game in java

I have 2 players

Player 1 uses the Up arrow key to move and Space to brake.
Player 2 uses Down key to move right.

I want the background to scroll properly, any help? I have this code:

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.*;
     import javax.swing.Timer;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.util.*;

     public class GLMBRace extends JFrame implements ActionListener
     {

    JLabel myBackground=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GLMBRace\\background.png"));
    JLabel player=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GLMBRace\\player_r.gif"));
    JLabel enemy=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GLMBRace\\enemy_r.gif"));

    int bgx=0;//background x
    int x=0,y=0,speed,prevx; //player x,y,speed
    int ex=0,ey=0,espeed; //enemy
    int time=50;

    Timer timer=new Timer(time,this);

    public GLMBRace(){
    Container c=getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
        player.setBounds(x,y,128,128);
        enemy.setBounds(ex,ey,96,96);
        myBackground.setBounds(bgx,0,10000,755);
    c.add(player);
    c.add(enemy);
    c.add(myBackground);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1366,768);

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

            String key = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());  
                if(key.equals("Space"))
                {
                    if(speed>0)
                    speed--;
                    timer.start();
                }
                if(key.equals("Up"))
                {
                    if(speed<20)
                    {
                    speed++;
                    ex-=speed;
                    }
                    timer.start();
                }
                if(key.equals("Down"))
                {
                    if(espeed<20)
                    {
                    espeed++;
                    x-=espeed;
                    }
                    timer.start();
                }
            }});//end keyevent

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==timer)
        {

            if(x>ex)
            {
            bgx-=speed;
            }
            if(ex>x)
            {
            bgx-=espeed;
            }
            player.setBounds(x,y,128,128);
            enemy.setBounds(ex,ey,96,96);
            myBackground.setBounds(bgx,0,10000,755);
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GLMBRace s = new GLMBRace();
        s.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

I really want to have the background scroll properly around the sprites, say if player 1 is faster, the background is centered on player 1. But if player 2 is faster, it will center on player 2. The code works only if 1 sprite is moving, but won't if 2 are moving.

It's a very simple code, can you guys teach me how to fix it? I love you.

Comment: What exactly is that "background"? It is (should be) just highlighting for the winning player?

Comment: No, Its an image that is the Game's background like a race track. It's a picture, all of the JLabels are pictures

Comment: Ah, you have 10000px wide picture which you "moves" back when going forward, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving your background dependent on the position of one of player, its position is determined by their position, therefore there is no need to have variable "bgx", you can always count this position by the position of player.

You can do this by creating simple method like this:

```
public int backgroundPosition(){
    if (x > ex){
        return x;
    } else {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

And then change your line for printing background to this :

```
myBackground.setBounds(-backgroundPosition(),0,10000,755);
```